# Duplicate object : Apex class fail to deploy

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, duplicate-value

This code worked for me for the creation of a new template as well as a section, but when I added the creation of a new question.
I found a problem in the deployment, I will put all the code in order to better understand and I will indicated the exact line where I have the problem, if anyone of you can help me .

```
 @AuraEnabled 
  public static void getFormTemplateName(Id TemplateId, string sapValue){

    Form_Template__c newFormTemplate = new Form_Template__c();
   Form_Template__c formTemplate = [SELECT Id ,Name,RecordTypeId,Form_Template_ID__c FROM Form_Template__c 
                                                  WHERE Id =:TemplateId];
    Sales_Organization__c salesOrg = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Sales_Organization__c WHERE SAP_Sales_Org_Code__c =: sapValue]; 
    
    newFormTemplate.RecordTypeId = formTemplate.RecordTypeId;
    newFormTemplate.Name = formTemplate.Name;
    newFormTemplate.Form_Template_ID__c = sapValue+'-'+formTemplate.Name;
    newFormTemplate.Sales_Organization__c = salesOrg.Id;
     
    insert newFormTemplate;

    Id formTemp = newFormTemplate.Id;
    List<Form_Template_Section__c> formTemplateSection = [SELECT Section_ID__c,  Name,Form_Template__c ,Order_Position__c  FROM Form_Template_Section__c 
    WHERE Form_Template__c =: TemplateId ];
  
    List<Form_Template_Section__c> newSection = new List<Form_Template_Section__c>();
    
    for (Form_Template_Section__c section : formTemplateSection){
    Form_Template_Section__c newSectionW = new Form_Template_Section__c();
      newSectionW.Form_Template__c = formTemp;
    newSectionW.Name = section.Name;
    newSectionW.Order_Position__c = section.Order_Position__c;
    newSectionW.Section_ID__c = newFormTemplate.Form_Template_ID__c+'-' +'SECT'+section.Order_Position__c +'teste';
    newSection.add(newSectionW);
    }
    system.debug('sizzze' + newSection.size());
    insert newSection;
```

=>I have problem in this line ,I can't deploy my code and I get as error that : Variable does not exist: Id  .
I use this method to get the Id of the New Section ( it is a lookup with the object Form_Template_Question__c )

```
    Id sectionFormTemp = newSection.Id;
```

```
   List<Form_Template_Question__c> formTemplateQuestion =
          [SELECT Question__c,Order_Position__c  ,Question_ID__c ,
   Form_Template_Section__c ,Form_Template__c 
          FROM Form_Template_Question__c WHERE Form_Template__c=: TemplateId ];

   List<Form_Template_Question__c> newQuestion = new List<Form_Template_Question__c>();


   for (Form_Template_Question__c question : formTemplateQuestion){

    Form_Template_Question__c newQuestionW= new Form_Template_Question__c();
    
     newQuestionW.Question__c = question.Question__c;
     newQuestionW.Order_Position__c = question.Order_Position__c;
    

     newQuestionW.Form_Template__c = formTemp;
     newQuestionW.Form_Template_Section__c = sectionFormTemp;
     
   
     newQuestionW.Question_ID__c = newFormTemplate.Form_Template_ID__c+'-' +'QUEST'+question.Order_Position__c +'teste';

     newQuestion.add(newquestionW);
     }
     
     insert newQuestion;

  

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`newSection` is a `List<Form_Template_Section__c>`, so the error is correct that `newSection.Id` does not exist. You'll need to figure out which section the question belongs to and use the appropriate ID from there.

That logic should look something like this:

```
Map<Id, Form_Template_Section__c> newSection = new Map<Id, Form_Template_Section__c>();

for (Form_Template_Section__c section : formTemplateSection){
    Form_Template_Section__c newSectionW = new Form_Template_Section__c();
    newSectionW.Form_Template__c = formTemp;
    newSectionW.Name = section.Name;
    newSectionW.Order_Position__c = section.Order_Position__c;
    newSectionW.Section_ID__c = newFormTemplate.Form_Template_ID__c+'-' +'SECT'+section.Order_Position__c +'teste';
    newSection.put(section.Id, newSectionW);
}
insert newSection.values();
```

---

```
for (Form_Template_Question__c question : formTemplateQuestion){
  Id sectionFormTemp = newSection.get(question.Form_Template_Section__c);
  // ... rest of logic
```

Comment: how can I determin which section the question belongs to for  using the appropriate ID

Comment: I suppose you probably need a `Map<Id, Form_Template_Section__c>` to link the old section Id to the new one; let me write up a demo.

Comment: ok thank's for your help